# With Dafny, verify function to count integer set elements less than a threshold

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

I'm open to any way of writing CountLessThan that is verifiable. Here is what I have:

```
function SetLessThan(numbers: set<int>, threshold: int): set<int>
{
  set i | i in numbers && i < threshold
}
method CountLessThan(numbers: set<int>, threshold: int) returns (count: int)
  ensures count == |SetLessThan(numbers, threshold)|
{
  count := 0;
  var shrink := numbers;
  var grow := {};
  while |shrink | > 0
    decreases shrink
    invariant shrink + grow == numbers
    invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
  {
    var i: int :| i in shrink;
    shrink := shrink - {i};
    grow := grow + {i};
    if i < threshold {
      count := count + 1;
    }
  }
}

method Main()
{
  var s: set<int> := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  var c: int := CountLessThan(s, 4);
  print c;
  // assert c == 3;

}
```

*This is one small step to defining a sorted set, then a sorted map, then a range set.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a classic verification debugging exercise ahead of you :)

The basic approach to verification debugging is to add `assert` statements to narrow down where your problem is.

I wrote out a full transcript of an idealized debugging session. Feel free to skip to the end if you just want the working code.

The code in your post reports the following error on the loop invariant:

```
while |shrink | > 0
  decreases shrink
  invariant shrink + grow == numbers

  invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
    // Error: might not be maintained
{
  var i: int :| i in shrink;
  shrink := shrink - {i};
  grow := grow + {i};
  if i < threshold {
    count := count + 1;
  }
}
```

This means Dafny could not re-establish the invariant at the bottom of the loop. Let's convert this into an assertion.

```
while |shrink | > 0
  decreases shrink
  invariant shrink + grow == numbers
  invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
{
  var i: int :| i in shrink;
  shrink := shrink - {i};
  grow := grow + {i};
  if i < threshold {
    count := count + 1;
  }
  assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;  // Error: might not hold
}
```

We haven't really done anything, but notice that the error on the invariant is no longer reported, so there's only one error total. That is Dafny saying "if you could prove the assertion, then the rest of the code would also verify".

Now we start moving the assertion backwards up the loop. The easiest way to move it into a one-sided if statement is to artificially introduce an empty `else` branch and then make a copy of the assertion in both sides.

```
while |shrink | > 0
  decreases shrink
  invariant shrink + grow == numbers
  invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
{
  var i: int :| i in shrink;
  shrink := shrink - {i};
  grow := grow + {i};
  if i < threshold {
    count := count + 1;
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;  // Error: might not hold
  } else {
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;  // Error: might not hold
  }
  assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
}
```

Notice that the error on the bottom-most `assert` is gone. We have two errors, but if we can fix those we are done. We are making progress.

In the first branch, we now move the `assert` back across the assignment. To do this, we replace occurrences of `count` with `count + 1` in the `assert`:

```
while |shrink | > 0
  decreases shrink
  invariant shrink + grow == numbers
  invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
{
  var i: int :| i in shrink;
  shrink := shrink - {i};
  grow := grow + {i};
  if i < threshold {
    assert count + 1 == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|; // Error: might not hold
    count := count + 1;
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
  } else {
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;  // Error: might not hold
  }
  assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
}
```

Notice still only two errors.

Now we need to pull the assert out of the top of the `if`. The easiest way to do that is with an `if`-expression.

```
while |shrink | > 0
  decreases shrink
  invariant shrink + grow == numbers
  invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
{
  var i: int :| i in shrink;
  shrink := shrink - {i};
  grow := grow + {i};
  assert if i < threshold
    then (count + 1 == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|)  // Error
    else count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;  // Error
  if i < threshold {
    assert count + 1 == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
    count := count + 1;
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
  } else {
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
  }
  assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
}
```

Dafny shows still shows separate errors for the two branches, but they are now all part of one `assert` statement again, more progress.

Next we move back across the assignment to `grow`. We substitute `grow + {i}` for `grow` in the assert.

```
while |shrink | > 0
  decreases shrink
  invariant shrink + grow == numbers
  invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
{
  var i: int :| i in shrink;
  shrink := shrink - {i};

  assert if i < threshold
    then (count + 1 == |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|)
    else count == |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|;
  // Error: might not hold

  grow := grow + {i};
  assert if i < threshold
    then (count + 1 == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|)
    else count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
  if i < threshold {
    assert count + 1 == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
    count := count + 1;
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
  } else {
    assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
  }
  assert count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|;
}
```

We have successfully moved the error again.

We could keep going back across the `shrink` assignment, but because it is not relevant to this assertion it doesn't matter, so let's just stay here.

At this point, we have eliminated all the "imperative stuff" in the verification problem, and we only have "logical stuff" left to worry about. Let's prove this assertion.

First, we can rewrite the assertion to pull the `==` out of the `if-then-else`. Put this `assert` above the previous one.

```
assert (if i < threshold then count + 1 else count) ==
  |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|;
```

This is now our only error, so we are still making progress. Dafny will prove the rest if we can prove this.

We can pull out the occurrence of `count` as well. Put this assert above the previous one.

```
assert count + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0) == 
  |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|;
```

We will prove this with a `calc`ulation block. Put this block above the previous assertion.

```
calc {
  count + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0);
  |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|;  // Error: might not equal previous line
}
```

We have a loop invariant about `count`, so let's substitute that in.

```
calc {
  count + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0);
  |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)| + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0);
  |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|;  // Error
}
```

Still only one error, so Dafny agrees with the first step of our calculation.

To fill the gap between the second and third lines, we need to connect the sets `SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)` and `SetLessThan(grow, threshold)`. How are they connected? Well if `i < threshold` then the former is the latter plus `i`, and otherwise they are just equal. Let's say that.

```
assert SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold) ==
  SetLessThan(grow, threshold) + (if i < threshold then {i} else {});
calc {
  count + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0);
  |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)| + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0);
  |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|;  // Error
}
```

Note that there's no error on the assert at the top! So Dafny likes our set equality but still can't prove the cardinality fact.

Let's try to fill the gap between the second and third lines by pulling the cardinality operator outside the plus.

```
calc {
  count + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0);
  |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)| + (if i < threshold then 1 else 0);
  |SetLessThan(grow, threshold) + (if i < threshold then {i} else {})|;  // Error: might not equal previous line
  |SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold)|;
}
```

Aha! The error moved. Now the last and second to last lines are equal, but the middle two lines are not. What gives?

Well, the cardinality of a union is *not* always the sum of the cardinalities. That's only true if they're disjoint. Are these sets disjoint? Yes! Why? because we pulled `i` out of shrink, and `grow` and `shrink` are disjoint. But Dafny can't tell because we need another loop invariant.

In Dafny, `A !! B` means `A` and `B` are disjoint.

We add this loop invariant:

```
invariant grow !! shrink
```

All the errors are gone!!! Wooo. We celebrate.

And now we clean up. We added a ton of needless assertions that we can now delete and figure out what really mattered. Just try deleting stuff and seeing what still verifies.

It turns out the only things that matter are the loop invariant and one `assert`. Here is the final loop

```
while |shrink | > 0
  decreases shrink
  invariant shrink + grow == numbers
  invariant grow !! shrink
  invariant count == |SetLessThan(grow, threshold)|
{
  var i: int :| i in shrink;
  shrink := shrink - {i};
  assert SetLessThan(grow + {i}, threshold) ==
    SetLessThan(grow, threshold) + if i < threshold then {i} else {};
  grow := grow + {i};
  if i < threshold {
    count := count + 1;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help! With some help from Divyanshu Ranjan, I got everything working. We wrote up our experience and reference your "mini-tutorial" in Rule 8 of https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-to-formally-validate-rust-algorithms-with-dafny-part-2-f2a279686700